# html - sharepoint form - copy date value from email and paste into form as date

Tags: html

Not too familiar with html - the code I'm using to try to paste into a date field in my form is as follows:

`timeFormat = Date.parse(time.substring(6)) $('#txtDateNotice').val(timeFormat.toString('M/d/yyyy')) $('#txtDateAbsence').val(timeFormat.toString('M/d/yyyy'))`

However, the form's field is formatted as a date in order for the user to have the calendar selector available if needed.  Is there a way to format this as a date rather than string in the html?